# Importing GDAL in spyder from a local GUI in cygwin

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, anaconda, cygwin

I have installed anaconda on linux (python 2.7).  Since gdal is not pre-loaded I load it with `conda install gdal`, which is fine.

When I do:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

I get the following error though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-e4290214a986>", line 5, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal

  File "/home/spotter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()

  File "/home/spotter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)

ImportError: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have done this same process on a windows with anaconda and gdal but no error.

My linux is Red Hat Enterprise Linux ComputeNode release 6.7 (Santiago)

EDIT:

Ok i think I am onto something.  What I am doing is using cygwin to enter a linux machine from a windows 7 computer. Within the linux machine if I do `python -c "import gdal"` all is fine.  The hang up is that I also want to use spyder linked to a gui in my local machine.  To get spyder to startup I need to change the PATH to `export PATH=/home/usrname/anaconda2/bin:$PATH`

as soon as I do this I must break some sort of connection with gdal.

Comment: that line resulted in `PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels:
  - source`

Comment: Yep, sorry about that.  I did those two commands, then started python with `ipython` and then `import gdal` which resulted in the same error.

Comment: Please, check it out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099981/why-cant-python-find-shared-objects-that-are-in-directories-in-sys-path. It can help.